# change drop down list using vba - combo box in forms

Tags: excel, vba

How do I access the drop down list to be able to change the ListFillRange?

```
If Worksheets("home").Range("K17").Value = "December" Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 2")).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "Lists!$D$16:$D$27"
        .LinkedCell = "Home!$J$11"
        .DropDownLines = 12
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With
    Else
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 2")).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "Lists!$D$2:$D$13"
        .LinkedCell = "Home!$J$11"
        .DropDownLines = 12
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With
End If
```

When I run this code I get the error

> Requested shapes are locked for selection

Comment: Are these comboboxes from the Forms menu?

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: yes, they are from the Forms menu